# npm run serve/yarn serve is not working upon restarting('node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.)

Tags: vue.js

It used to work but when I restarted my PC it won't work anymore. The nodejs directory is set in the Path environmental variable. I tried reinstalling nodejs. I also tried uninstalling @vue folder, running my git bash as administrator, and opening and reopening the terminal. Nothing is currently working. How can I fix this?

**Error**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Mariel\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'serve' ]
2 info using npm@6.0.0
3 info using node@v10.0.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preserve', 'serve', 'postserve' ]
5 info lifecycle vue-proj@0.1.0~preserve: vue-proj@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle vue-proj@0.1.0~serve: vue-proj@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle vue-proj@0.1.0~serve: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle vue-proj@0.1.0~serve: PATH: C:\Users\Mariel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Mariel\Code\vue-proj\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Mariel\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Mariel\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Sony\VAIO Improvement;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO Startup Setting Tool;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;.;C:\xampp\php";C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\Mariel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Mariel\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Program Files\nodej;C:\Users\Mariel\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
9 verbose lifecycle vue-proj@0.1.0~serve: CWD: C:\Users\Mariel\Code\vue-proj
10 silly lifecycle vue-proj@0.1.0~serve: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'vue-cli-service serve' ]
11 silly lifecycle vue-proj@0.1.0~serve: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle vue-proj@0.1.0~serve: Failed to exec serve script
13 verbose stack Error: vue-proj@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mariel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:283:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mariel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:947:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:236:5)
14 verbose pkgid vue-proj@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Mariel\Code\vue-proj
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Mariel\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "serve"
18 verbose node v10.0.0
19 verbose npm  v6.0.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error vue-proj@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the vue-proj@0.1.0 serve script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**Dependencise(package.json)**

```
{


"name": "vue-proj",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.0-beta.9",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.0.0-beta.9",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.0-beta.9",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.13"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@vue/app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ]
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Just found out it's the terminal's fault. I tried using another terminal and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

re-install the npm package manager

or update node to **LTS** Version